# Wrong URL redirecting me to correct site - how is this done?

Tags: html, url

When i type a certain wrong URL in my browser (Chrome/Edge), I don't get a page not found, but instead I'm taken to a similar website.
I like this behaviour but I'm curious how this happens.

In the case I'm thinking about I type the following correct URL which takes me to a page about cancer mortality from 1951:

```
http://www-dep.iarc.fr/NORDCAN/English/Table1.asp?cancer=510&registry=208&sYear=**1951**&eYear=2014&sex=1&type=1&age_from=1&age_to=18&submit=Execute
```

Notice the 1951 above which indicates the first year of the table. If I type the same URL but with 1950 or 1949 I'm still taken to the same website with data from 1951 (as data for 1950 or 1949 does not exist).

```
http://www-dep.iarc.fr/NORDCAN/English/Table1.asp?cancer=510&registry=208&sYear=**1950**&eYear=2014&sex=1&type=1&age_from=1&age_to=18&submit=Execute
```

What is this redirection or guessing called? How is this happening? Is it the browser or the HTML? Normally when I type a URL that does not exist, I get a "website does not exist"-error, but in this case I do not. Why is this?

Feel free to edit the title into something better, because I don't know what this behavior is called.

Comment: There's no redirection, those are the same page `http://www-dep.iarc.fr/NORDCAN/English/Table1.asp` The additional data is probably being used to tell the page what to display.

Comment: When I type in http://www-dep.iarc.fr/NORDCAN/English/Table1.asp it tells me that this website does not exist. Anyway, if the additional data tell the page what to display, why does it display something different than what the additional data describes? Why does it display 1951 data when I write 1950 in the URL. I would have expected a "page not found"?

Comment: It's all down to whatever code (probably server-side) is handling the request. I would guess that the data in that URL is not valid, and the server is serving the closest possible data it can find. Either that or there's a bug in the code, but as we can't see that it's impossible to know exactly what's going on, we can only make assumptions.

Comment: @DBS, write it in an answer and I will accept it. I did not know that it could be server-side, so this answers my question as much as possible with the available information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string (data shown after the `?`) is used by the server to generate the data shown on the page.

We can't see exactly what's happening on the server, but I would say it's likely that the "redirection" is the server finding the closest possible data to what's been requested, and adjusting the URL accordingly.